# Change Formula =Hyperlink Cell Value

Tags: string, excel, hyperlink, formula

I am trying to change a large listing in excel to hyperlink to a location I have specified. The issue is that the "location" will need to slightly change as well. The url/hyperlink ends with a `=` + `ID`

example url:
`http://.../.../.../Display=Search&SearchFld=ID&DisplayType=Simple&DisplayValue=13`

Excel Listing

```
     A   B                F
A1  ID  Subject       =HYPERLINK("http://.../.../.../Display=Search&SearchFld=ID&DisplayType=Simple&DisplayValue=" & A2, F2)
A2  13  E Service     =HYPERLINK("http://.../.../.../Display=Search&SearchFld=ID&DisplayType=Simple&DisplayValue=" & A3, F3)
A3  39  AD Request        ....
A4  99  Request Email     ....
..etc
```

My issue is that when I add this formula, it creates a `0` inside the cell when What I want is it to show `Subject` hyperlinked, `E Service` hyperlinked and so forth.

**So column F should show column B's text but hyperlink.**

[image]

Comment: Are you getting a circular reference warning? You're referring to column F inside column F. I find it strange that you would create a hyperlink in F1 that refers to the data in rows 2 (so I assume that it was just a typo), but then you say you want it show 'Subject' which is clearly a column header and not actual data. Why would you want that?

Comment: That was a mistake. Yes Subject is the header and I mean't to say E Service, AD Request... etc to be the hyperlink text within the cell. I chose F column to have hyperlink because if I type the formula in Column B, my cell values change to `0` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the second argument of HYPERLINK `B2`. If I replicate your data in A1:B4, this formula in F2 produces the correct result.

```
=HYPERLINK("http://.../.../.../Display=Search&SearchFld=ID&DisplayType=Simple&DisplayValue=" & A2, B2)
```

Comment: I should have known it was an easy fix :/ Thank you for the example version. This works to what I needed.